# asp.net 2010 with c# and access 2003

Tags: asp.net, ms-access-2003

I am new to asp.net and am building a site for hotel. I need to compare the check in date with check out date stored in an access database.  The result is shown via a data grid but when I compare it, I get a data type mismatch criteria expression. I can connect to the access database and I use a calendar to pass the date via a textbox.

This is my code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ds = new DataSet();
    st ="select * from abc where status = 'v'and checkout= '" + Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text) + "'";
    adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(st, cn);
    int r = adp.Fill(ds, "app");
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataMember = "app";
    GridView1.DataBind();
    int intCount;
    intCount = ds.Tables["app"].Rows.Count;
    Label1.Text = intCount.ToString();

}

protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yy");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do NOT build the SQL query yourself use a parameterised query instead you are setting yourself up for a big fall. This should take care of the formatting for you.

For example:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ds = new DataSet();

    // this has changed...
    st ="select * from abc where status = 'v'and checkout= @date";

    adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(st, cn);

    // this is new...
    adp.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text));

    int r = adp.Fill(ds, "app");
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataMember = "app";
    GridView1.DataBind();
    int intCount;
    intCount = ds.Tables["app"].Rows.Count;
    Label1.Text = intCount.ToString();

}

protected void Calendar1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox1.Text = Calendar1.SelectedDate.ToString("MM/dd/yy");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Access queries need the date format to be '#YYYY-MM-DD#', including the # symbols and surrounded by single quotes.

Rather than formatting the string yourself, consider using parameters in your query and a command object as it will automatically handle the formatting for you.

For the simplest change, amend your line which creates the SQL to the following:

```
st ="select * from abc where status = 'v'and checkout= '#" + Convert.ToDateTime(TextBox1.Text).ToString("YYYY-MM-DD") + "#'";
```

Comment: sorry i cant understand. pls detail the proceding.